# uiImageView error with SDWebImage

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

After adding SDWebImage lib and putting their standard code:

> [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL
>   URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
>                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

I get the next error:

> ViewController.m: error: Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Receiver type 'UIImageView' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:'

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentations](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) says, you should import [`"UIImageView+WebCache.h"`](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/UIImageView+WebCache.h), which is the header where the method `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:` is declared in a `UIImageView` category.

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"

// ...

[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Comment: Oh shit, I thought I added it already... Thank you very much!